# Adding ornament on section titles using titlesec and pgfornaments

Tags: tikz-pgf, titlesec

I want to add an ornament (provided by the `pgfornament` package) after the section title's body. Here is a MWE which produces the error I get (the document compiles correctly if I remove `\pgfornament[width=0.25\textwidth]{70}`):

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\usepackage[calcwidth]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\centering}{\thesection\\}{0pt}{\huge}[\pgfornament[width=0.25\textwidth]{70}]
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\section{A section}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

I want it to look like :

```
                                                section number
                                                section title
                                                   ornament
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `\protect`

```
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\centering}{\thesection\\}{0pt}{\huge}[\protect{\pgfornament[width=0.25\textwidth]{70}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome lovely answer! For my case, how do I place the Number before the Section Title (on the same line)  and how do I modify the spacing between Title and ornament?